# Filter out invalid PIDs portably

Tags: bash, shell, sh, posix

I wrote a script to fetch the Top Level Session PID, that is, the session starter, who may be a shell like bash, dash, ksh, or even systemd. The script may get a PID as a initial parameter however I need to filter it to check it is a valid integer and not something like `34fg45`, `-5467` and I don't want it starting with a zero like `05467`.

This is a snippet of the script.

```
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    if [[ "$1" == [1-9]*([0-9]) ]]; then                <- Check for Integer; error here in non bash shell 
        if ps -p $1 -o "pid=" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            pid=$1
        else
            echo "PID $1, no such process." >&2
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        echo "Invalid pid." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
else
    pid=$$
fi
```

The code runs in bash, but fails to run on dash with a syntax error:

```
./tspid: 16: ./tspid: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

It is my understanding that

`if [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9][1-9]*$ ]];` using `=~` does regular expression matching, and
`if [[ "$1" == [1-9]*([0-9]) ]];` using `==` does pattern matching

1. Is that right?
2. How to transform the above expressions to run in both, non-bash as well in bash shells ?

Answer (score 6):

Use [case conditional construct](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05). Every POSIX shell has it and unlike double brackets it doesn't look horrible.

```
# make sure 0-9 is literally 0 to 9
LC_COLLATE=C
# assume set -u is not in effect or $1 is set
case $1 in
('')
  # handle empty argument
  ;;
(0*|*[!0-9]*)
  # handle invalid PID (0, 042, 42a, etc.)
  ;;
(*)
  # handle valid PID
  ;;
esac
# restore LC_COLLATE if necessary
```